# Does SN44.9 imply an intermediate state between births?

Tags: theravada, rebirth

According to [Kutuhalasala Sutta (SN44.9)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn44/sn44.009.than.html), translated by Thanissaro Bhikkhu:

> **Vacchagotta:** "And at the moment when a being sets this body aside and is not yet reborn in another body, what do you designate as its
>   sustenance then?"
>
> **Buddha:** "Vaccha, when a being sets this body aside and is not yet reborn in another body, I designate it as craving-sustained, for
>   craving is its sustenance at that time."

Alternative translation by Bhikkhu Bodhi [here](https://suttacentral.net/sn44.9/en/bodhi):

> **Vacchagotta:** “And, Master Gotama, when a being has laid down this body but has not yet been reborn in another body, what does Master
>   Gotama declare to be its fuel on that occasion?”
>
> **Buddha:** “When, Vaccha, a being has laid down this body but has not yet been reborn in another body, I declare that it is fuelled by
>   craving. For on that occasion craving is its fuel.”

In the Theravada tradition, the orthodox doctrine based on the Abhidhamma states that there is no intermediate state between births, that rebirth-linking consciousness instantaneously results in a new birth without any gaps.

However, the above sutta implies that it is possible to have an intermediate state that is sustained by craving.

So, my question is: does SN44.9 imply an intermediate state between births, or is there an alternative interpretation for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Piya Tan has an essay on the topic here: [Is Rebirth Immediate? (SD 2.17)](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/2.17-Is-rebirth-immediate.-piya-1.pdf)

And a commentary and translation of the sutta here, [Kutūhala,sālā Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/23.15-Kutuhalasala-S-s44.9-piya.pdf), which includes "To Vaccha’s second and final question, the Buddha makes his famous statement on the intermediate state."

My paraphrase of the essay (if I've read it correctly) is that:

- The Abhidhamma and commentaries denies an intermediate state, on not very strong grounds (e.g. that the Buddha didn't teach explicitly that there is such a thing)
- Many people (Theravada and other schools) believe in such a state anyway
- There are suttas (which it quotes) which may be describing an intermediate state
- Other sources include the Chinese Agamas, and the Sanskrit, the Milinda Panha

That essay totals about 15 pages -- you can read the details.

It quotes Ven. Sujato's commentary on The Kutūhala,sāla Sutta:

> From this we can conclude that the Buddha, following ideas current in his time—for Vacchagotta
>   was a non-Buddhist wanderer (paribbājaka)—accepted that there was some kind of interval
>   between one life and the next. During this time, when one has “laid down” this body, but is not
>   yet reborn in another, one is sustained by craving, like a flame tossed by the wind is sustained by
>   air. The simile suggests, perhaps, that the interval is a short one; but the purpose of the simile is to
>   illustrate the dependent nature of the period, not the length of time it takes. While a fire is burning
>   normally, it is sustained by a complex of factors, such as fuel, oxygen, and heat. But when a
>   tongue of flame is momentarily tossed away from the source fire, it can last only a short while,
>   and in that time it is tenuously sustained by the continued supply of oxygen. Similarly in our
>   lives, we are sustained by food, sense stimulus, and so on, but in the in-between, it is only the
>   slender thread of craving that propels us forward. The difference is, of course, that the flame will
>   easily go out, while the fuel of craving propels the unawakened inexorably into future rebirth.